# Concate String In MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can i concate this string in mysql

```
desc=desc+$desct
```

what i want is each time i insert a variable from PHP that the string is added to the string which was already in db and seperated with **||**

the field desc should look like this

```
desc
10||30||90||710
```

say i want to add the value 20

```
desc
10||30||90||710||20
```

then the desc field should look like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use MySQL [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName = CONCAT(colName, "||20") WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$mysql_desct = mysql_real_escape_string($desct, $mysqlconnection);
$query = "
  UPDATE
    tblFoo
  SET
    desc = Concat(desc, '||', '$mysql_desct')
";
mysql_query($query, $mysqlconnection) or die(mysql_error());
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat