# Exploding a String In PHP

Tags: php, explode

How do i explode this string `'||25||34||73||94||116||128'` 
i need to have a array like this

```
array (
 0 => '25',
 1 => '34',
 2 => '73',
 3 => '94',
 4 => '116',
 5 => '128'
)
```

explode("||", $array); didnt work for me i get this array

```
array (
 0 => '',
 1 => '25',
 2 => '34',
 3 => '73',
 4 => '94',
 5 => '116',
 6 => '128',
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$array = explode('||', trim($string, '|'));
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution, especially **if you can have empty values in the middle of the string**, could be to use **[`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) and its `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag** :

```
$str = '||25||34||73||94||116||128';
$array = preg_split('/\|\|/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($array);
```

Will give you :

```
array
  0 => string '25' (length=2)
  1 => string '34' (length=2)
  2 => string '73' (length=2)
  3 => string '94' (length=2)
  4 => string '116' (length=3)
  5 => string '128' (length=3)
```

If you'll never have *empty values* in the middle of the string, though, using `explode` will be faster, even if you have to remove the `||` at the beginning and end of the string before calling it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str='||25||34||73||94||116||128';
$s = array_filter(explode("||",$str),is_numeric);
print_r($s);
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 34
    [3] => 73
    [4] => 94
    [5] => 116
    [6] => 128
)
```

Comment: What if there is a value `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Since [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468742/concate-string-in-mysql) was how to store and update such a string in MySQL  ...let's assume for a moment one of your future tasks will be to find out if a certain value is in this array/string or to find/count all records that have a certain value in this array.
In that case you *might* want to start [normalizing your table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
explode('||',substr($str,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already mentioned solutions, you could also filter out the empty values afterwards:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode("||", $str), function($val) { return trim($val) === ""; });
```

This example uses an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that you would need to replace if you’re not using PHP 5.3 or greater, either using [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function):

```
$arr = array_filter(explode("||", $str), create_function('$val', 'return trim($val) === "";'));
```

Or with a predefined function:

```
function isEmptyString($str) {
    return trim($str) === "";
}
$arr = array_filter(explode("||", $str), "isEmptyString");
```